# Determine the current in the following op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

[image]

It is required to find \$i_O\$ given that \$V_{SRC}=2V\$

I assumed a node voltage \$V_1\$ as shown in the figure. Therefore, since we have an op-amp then the votlage at both input terminals are also V1. This means that the current passsing through \$R1\$ is \$\dfrac{2-V1}{4k}\$ from left to right. Using this we can see that the voltage difference across R2 is \$2(2-V_1)\$. And with further KCL we can see that the node voltage of R6 is \$V_0=3V_1-4\$.

Comment: First, figure out what the gain is, noting that you have both positive and negative feedback.  Then you should be able to find the output for a given input.  The current is then that output voltage divided by the resistor on the output.

Comment: Remember that, for an ideal op-amp, the differential voltage Vd tends to be 0 in the high-gain region

Comment: The difference between this question, and say http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/100269/2028, is in the wording and how it is presented. For example, this one doesn't actually ask a question, it contains directives like "It is required to find..." as if robotic. The other one doesn't actually ask a question either, but is stated using less demanding language: "We are supposed to find... [but] I am not sure how to go about this." Basically, re-formulating this to ask a clear question and show how and from where you derived formulas from would probably help a lot.

Comment: @JYelton Thank you for highlighting the difference. Its interesting how such subtle nuances can lead to vastly different responses. Regardless, though I am happy to see that there are some people who discuss before making assumptions and down-voting.

Answer (score 1):

The next step in solving this is to figure out the relationship between V<sub>src</sub> and V1, which is basically the voltage drop across R1.

Since all of the current that flows through R1 must also flow through R2 (the opamp is assumed to have infinite input impedance), and since you know the relationship between V1 and V0, it should be straightforward to calculate what that current is.

Once you have the relationship between V<sub>src</sub> and V1, and since you already have the relationship between V1 and V0, you can combine the results to get the overall relationship between V<sub>src</sub> and V0. From there, you get the relationship between V<sub>src</sub> and I<sub>0</sub>.

Comment: Good pointers for a homework exercise

Comment: I found V0 using the V_SRC which gives \$V_0=3V_1 -4\$

Comment: @user29568: Actually, that result is incorrect. The relationship between V1 and V0 is determined entirely by R4 and R5, assuming the opamp is operating in a regime in which negative feedback is working as expected. Of course, you'll verify that this assumption is true once you have an overall solution.

Comment: @DaveTweed I am pretty sure its correct. Yeah it is defined by R4 and R5 as V1=0.4V0. And relating those two equations gives V0=20V as needed.